# Insert image in Google Sheets from python, PyExecJS, and JavaScript using PyScripter

Tags: javascript, python, pyscripter, execjs

I am trying to insert an image generated by Matplot into a Google Sheet from Python from PyScripter using Python 2.7.  This is the starting data from the csv:

```
   x    Date    orcl
0   10/17/2016  37.685646
20  11/14/2016  38.679703
40  12/13/2016  40.116657
60  1/12/2017   38.732384
80  2/10/2017   40.303417
100 3/13/2017   42.072063
120 4/10/2017   43.662434
140 5/9/2017    45.131077
160 6/7/2017    45.051693
180 7/6/2017    48.47522
200 8/3/2017    50.032654
220 8/31/2017   50.132263
240 9/29/2017   48.160038
260 10/27/2017  50.880001
280 11/27/2017  48.880001
```

Here are the imports:

```
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.api as sm
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
matplotlib.style.use('ggplot')
```

Get the data from the file and genereate the plots:

```
file = pd.read_csv('orcl.csv')
x = file.iloc[ :, -3]
y = file.iloc[ :, -1] 

m, b = np.polyfit(x, y, 1)
results = sm.OLS(y,x).fit()
print ('results are: ', (results))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.plot(x, y, '.', label = None)
plt.plot(x, m*x + b, '-',label='Regression Line')

ax.scatter(x, y)
ax.set_xlabel(r'days_from_start', fontsize=15)
ax.set_ylabel(r'stock_price', fontsize=15)
ax.grid(True)
fig.tight_layout()
plt.legend()
plt.savefig("orcl.png", bbox_inches='tight')
plt.show()
```

Pyscripter hangs up in a debug session, even though I have debug turned off in > Tools > Options > IDE Options > Postmortem on exception until I close the plot window. This code dose not close the plot:

```
plt.close()
```

I am having trouble with the ExecJS:

```
import execjs

    # execjs from here:  https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyExecJS
    # javascript from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/
    #43664483/insert-image-into-google-sheets-cell-using-google-sheets-api

ctx = execjs.compile( """    {
     var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
     var formulaSheet = ss.getSheetByName("orcl"); '''tab 'orcl' is present.
     var formulaCell = formulaSheet.getRange("B5");
     formulaCell.setFormula('=IMAGE("orcl.png",4,100,200)')
     }    #http://finviz.com/fut_chart.ashx?t=ES&p&p=m5&s=m

""")
import execjs.runtime_names
jscript = execjs.get(execjs.runtime_names.JScript)
jscript.eval(ctx)
```

Python says "exceptions, attribute error, context has no attribute 'strip'".

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So, in big picture, inserting an image in Google Sheets can be accomplished with Python by inserting the image file in Google Drive using the Google Drive API:

https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert#examples,

and then linking to the image in Google Sheets with the Google Sheets API,
https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets#CellData

This is a very long page, but the information on hyperlink is about 1/3 of the way down, under CellData

Comment: celldata is now at this link: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/cells#CellData